# Styling checkboxes and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm making some script for the commenting system, and fortunately everything is working out just fine except for a minor problem that is bothering me, during the ajax call.
When I call upon the page that makes the live data search with ajax, the check boxes do not look like they should.But when I put in the javascript code, the check boxes look the way they should, but then the function doesn't work.
Here is what the code looks like:

Ajax call

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

    load_data('');

    function load_data(query, typehead_search = 'yes')
    {
     $.ajax({
      url:"fetc.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:{query:query, typehead_search:typehead_search},
      success:function(data)
      {
       $('#email_data').html(data);
      }
     });
    }

    $('#email_search').typeahead({
     source: function(query, result){
      $.ajax({
       url:"fetc.php",
       method:"POST",
       data:{query:query},
       dataType:"json",
       success:function(data){
        result($.map(data, function(item){
         return item;
        }));
        load_data(query, 'yes');
       }
      });
     }
    });

 $(document).on('click', 'li', function(){
  var query = $(this).text();
  load_data(query);
 });
});
</script>
```

the page that does the live search data

```
 <?php
require_once("private/initialize.php"); 

//fetch.php
if(isset($_POST["query"])){
 $request = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST["query"]);
 $query = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE deleted = 2 AND comment_email LIKE '%".$request."%' ORDER BY comment_id DESC";



$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
 $data =array();?>
<?php
 $html = '';
 $html .= '
    <table class="table table-hover table-mail">
                    <tbody>';
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
  while($comment = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
   $data[] = $comment["comment_title"];
   $data[] = $comment["comment_email"];

   $html .= '
     <tr class="read" id="'.$comment["comment_id"].'">
        <td class="check-mail">
            <input type="checkbox" name="comment_id[]" class="i-checks delete_customer" value="'.$comment["comment_id"].'">
        </td>
        <td class="mail-ontact"><a href="mail_detail.php?comment='.$comment['comment_id'].'">'.$comment['comment_title'].'</a></td>
        <td class="mail-subject"><a href="mail_detail.php?id='.$comment['comment_id'].'">'.$comment['comment_email'].'</a></td>
        <td class=""></td>
        <td class="text-right mail-date">8.22 PM</td>
    </tr>
   ';
  }
 } 
 else{
  $data = 'No Data Found';
  $html .= '
   <tr>
    <td colspan="3">No Data Found</td>
   </tr>
   ';
 }
 $html .= '
     </tbody>
</table>';

 if(isset($_POST['typehead_search']))
 {
  echo $html;
 }
 else
 {
  $data = array_unique($data);
  echo json_encode($data);
 }
}
 ?>
 // the javascript that is making the problem
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.i-checks').iCheck({
            checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
            radioClass: 'iradio_square-green',
        });
    });
</script>
```

In advance, I am most grateful for any given help.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "checkboxes don't look the way they should"? Is their state not right, are they not displaying properly?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I mean by the buttons not looking as they should:

This is how it looks like with the java script code.
[image]

The buttons get the right look, but then the function doesn't work. But without the java code, the function works, but the buttons do not look as they should.

[image]

I would like both the function to work, and the buttons to look as they should. At the same time